# Installing Giggle 0.7 no makefile found and installation instructions are to 'make'

Tags: software-installation

I've been trying to follow the instructions for installing `giggle-0.7`.  From the `INSTALL` file:

> The simplest way to compile this package is:
>
> 1. `cd' to the directory containing the package's source code and type`
>      ./configure' to configure the package for your system.
>
>    Running `configure' might take a while.  While running, it prints
>       some messages telling which features it is checking for.
> 2. Type `make' to compile the package.

Unfortunately running `make` makes it rather obvious that there is no make file in the root package directory.  There are `Makefile.am` and `Makefile.in`, but running `make Makefile.am` and `make Makefile.in` doesn't do anything either.

The source is the tar file from [this gnome.org page](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/giggle/0.7/).

Any help is appreciated.

### Edit 1 OS

I'm installing on `CentOS 6.5`.

### Edit 2 config.log

The first sign of an error on `config.log`:

> ```
> configure:4058: checking for gcc option to accept ISO C99
> configure:4207: gcc  -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5 conftest.c:61: error:
> expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'text' conftest.c: In function 'main':
> conftest.c:115: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or
> '__attribute__' before 'newvar' conftest.c:115: error: 'newvar'
> undeclared (first use in this function) conftest.c:115: error: (Each
> undeclared identifier is reported only once conftest.c:115: error: for
> each function it appears in.) conftest.c:125: error: 'for' loop
> initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode conftest.c:125:
> note: use option -std=c99 or -std=gnu99 to compile your code
> configure:4207: $? = 1 configure: failed program was: | /* confdefs.h
> */ | #define PACKAGE_NAME "Giggle" | #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "giggle" | #define PACKAGE_VERSION "0.7" | #define PACKAGE_STRING "Giggle 0.7"
> ```

I'm currently trying to see if I can figure anything out about this.  Please let me know if I should post more (or all) of `config.log`.

Comment: Just to make sure: Is there a reason why you're compiling this by hand? Is there a package available for it, either in the official repositories, EPEL, or any other source? Are you aware of the dangers of `sudo make install`, which an unfortunate number of software developers instruct you to do when compiling their software?

Comment: @jayhendren I could use some help with "the dangers of sudo make install".

Comment: Basically, `make` can do whatever it wants - it can run arbitrary scripts, it can add, remove, and edit files, and it can do anything a user would be able to do. By running `make` with sudo, you're elevating the make script to root privileges and allowing to change the system in any way possible. Unless you're 110% confident that the Makefile won't screw with your system, it's not a good idea to run it with root privileges. Long story short: don't run anything with `sudo`, especially if it's just downloaded from a random developer, without knowing *exactly* what it does.

Comment: When compiling software, it's generally better to specify a prefix with `./configure --prefix=/path/to/somewhere` to specify an installation directory where you have permission to write. This way you control what the Makefile installs and you don't have to run `sudo make install`. You will also need to update your search path (`PATH`) and the locations that your linker searches for shared library objects in this case.

Comment: @jayhendren To me, this sounds almost exactly the same as running executables (.exe) in Windows.

Comment: @jayhendren Is it possible for installing via `sudo` or as `root` user to cause the installation to go awry?

Comment: Yes, that is why you should avoid it if at all possible. Makefiles are just fancy scripts. They run any command. So don't give a random script you downloaded from the internet root privileges.

Comment: @jayhendren Does not using `root` privileges apply for `yum` installation also?

Comment: No, yum carefully controls what files it installs. If you only use official repositories, then only official packages will be installed through yum. Sure, if you use yum to install a package built by a third party, then you will be taking some risk.

Answer (score 1):

The job of configure scripts is to create a Makefile. If there is no `Makefile` after running `configure`, then the `configure` script either:

- Didn't "run without a hitch" as you claim
- Is very poorly written

There should be a log file from the configuration script called something like `config.log`. See if you can find an error in there that would indicate why configuration didn't finish successfully.

Comment: Looking at config.log now.  Thank you for the tip.

Comment: There were hitches.  Edit 2 has removed the claim that there wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than try to debug a failed compiling, I've decided to use a different product.

I was looking for a `git` GUI that was native to Linux.  My first choice was [Giggle](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/giggle/), and my second was [gitg](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gitg/).  Unfortunately neither of these actually had `yum` repositories for `CentOS`.

I did a `yum search 'git'` and found QGit.  The `yum` installation was much easier and worked.  I plan on using `yum search` as my primary source more often in the future.